# Set an action for one element in ng-repet clause

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

i've this code and a little problem working with Ionic and AngularJS.

```
$scope.changeArrow = function(){
    if($scope.down == false){
      $scope.down = true;
    }else{
      $scope.down = false;
    }
};

<ion-item ng-repeat="beac in disp" class="item-icon-right" ng-click="changeArrow()">
  <b>{{choosen.network}} - {{beac.minor}}</b> •&nbsp;&nbsp;{{beac.viewed}} / {{beac.conf}}
  <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-b" ng-show="down"></i>
  <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b" ng-show="!down"></i>
```

Results:

[image: 1]

After click -->>

[image: 2]

After click, will be the first image.

The problem is that i need to change the arrow only in the selected item, not in all of them. I have no idea how can I do it with **Ionic**. Any 'special' method?

Thanks

Comment: ng-click='selectedItem=beak', ng-show="selectedItem==beak". You can do like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="beac in disp" class="item-icon-right" ng-click="selectedItem=beak">
  <b>{{choosen.network}} - {{beac.minor}}</b> •&nbsp;&nbsp;{{beac.viewed}} / {{beac.conf}}
  <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-b" ng-show="selectedItem!=beak"></i>
  <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b" ng-show="selectedItem==beak"></i>
```

Or even like this:

```
   <ion-item ng-repeat="beac in disp" class="item-icon-right" ng-click="selectedItem=beak">
  <b>{{choosen.network}} - {{beac.minor}}</b> •&nbsp;&nbsp;{{beac.viewed}} / {{beac.conf}}
  <i class="icon" ng-class="{'ion-arrow-down-b': beak==selectedItem, 'ion-arrow-right-b': beak!=selectedItem}"></i>
```

Comment: I have selected your answer but changing the ng-click with the function. <ion-item ng-repeat="beac in disp" class="item-icon-right" ng-click="changeArrow(beak)"> Something like this. That works. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Do you really need this function? It adds complexity to your controller.

Comment: I prefer to maintain the logic in the controller not in the view.

Comment: Well, guess it's a matter of taste then :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
$scope.changeArrow = function(index){
  $scope.down = index;
};
```

and then `ng-click="changeArrow($index)"`

and then `ng-show="down === $index"`

Answer (score 2):

Your `changeArrow` function is probably toggling the `down` variable which in turn change the arrows for all the items. You can pass the item index to this function to control which arrow will be facing down.

**Controller**

```
$scope.selectedItemIndex = -1;

$scope.changeArrow(index) {
    $scope.selectedItemIndex = index;   
}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="beac in disp" class="item-icon-right" ng-click="changeArrow($index)">
  <b>{{choosen.network}} - {{beac.minor}}</b> •&nbsp;&nbsp;{{beac.viewed}} / {{beac.conf}}
  <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-b" ng-show="$index === selectedItemIndex"></i>
  <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b" ng-show="$index !== selectedItemIndex"></i>
```